# What's the difference between program arguments and VM arguments?

Tags: java, eclipse

I found only when I put `-Dcontext=web` into VM arguments, the value can be read by `System.getproperty` method. I am wondering what's the difference between those two?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

**Program arguments** are arguments passed to your program and available in the `args` array of your main method

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
```

**VM arguments** are passed to the virtual machine and are designed to instruct the VM to do something.  You can do things like control the heap size, etc.  They can be accessed by your program via a call to `System.getProperty()` as you described.

Comment: Just to add a subtle point with regards to `-Djava.library.path=/path/to/folder/`. The `System.loadLibrary()` cannot link the native library despite `System.getProperty("java.library.path")` returns a string of  `/path/to/folder/` where your native library is located. For example in the Eclipse IDE, you have to specially set the value of this folder location in the IDE menu settings. Setting it programatically by `System.setProperty()` will not work.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

**Program Argument:** Program arguments are arguments that are passed to your application, which are accessible via the "args" String array parameter of your main method.

**VM Argument:** VM arguments are environment or system argument that needed by JVM to execute the program. VM arguments are read from system property as below java instruction.

> System.getProperty(sysProp1)

Code Snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sysProp1 = "sysProp1";
    System.out.println("\t System Propery Name:" + sysProp1 + ", Value:" + System.getProperty(sysProp1));
    System.out.println("\t Program Variable Test Propery Name:" + args[0]);
}
```

There are Two way to pass these two params values.

**From Eclipse**:

As shown in the figure above

**Command Line Argument**:

```
 java -cp -DsysProp1=testing123456 projectJar-2.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar 123
```

For a better presentation, in multiple lines

```
 java -cp 
      -DsysProp1=testing123456 
      projectJar-2.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar 
      123
```

Comment: BTW `VM Argument(s)` goes prior of the `jar` and uses `-D` and `Program Argument(s)` goes after of the `jar`

Answer (score 2):

The *Program args* are available via the `args []` of your `main(String args[])` method

Answer (score 2):

Program arguments go into main() method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) // here
```

Answer (score 1):

- Program arguments - arguments which we normally pass into our program. This type parameters can be accessed using "args" String array in the main method.
- VM arguments - arguments which are passed into the Java interpreter.