# Why is the System.getProperty not working in eclipse + Java 8?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

So in my run configuration in eclipse, I picked my main class `Main.java`, in the tab "Program Arguments" I put `testArg=Sample`.

In my application's `main` method, I do a:
`System.out.println` on:

1. `args[0]`
2. `System.getProperty("testArg")`

The result I get for `args[0`] is `testArg=Sample`, but the result I get for `System.getProperty("testArg")` is `null`.

What is going on? I am using Java 8 and the Eclipse Kepler.

NOTE:

When I put in "VM Arguments" box `testArg=Sample`, I get and error :

> Error: Could not find or load main class testArg=Sample`

Comment: What does `System.getProperty` do?

Comment: import java.util.Properties;

Comment: I don't think providing `testArg=Sample` as an argument does what you think it does.

Comment: and what is the value if testArg?

Comment: Use `java -Dtestarg=Sample ...` to set System properties

Answer (score 6, accepted):

System.getProperty() gets VM arguments usually specified with -D, these are typically used to configure the VM. Your argument is a 'program argument'.

See : [What's the difference between program arguments and VM arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751851/whats-the-difference-between-program-arguments-and-vm-arguments)

As you are using eclipse (Depending on version); you should be able to specify the VM arguments and the program arguments for a run configuration in the same place under the arguments tab:

- **Program Arguments** - passed as args[] to your main method
- **VM Arguments** - available through System.getProperty()

[image]

Comment: thkx `-D` is what I was not getting

Answer (score 1):

Per `java -h`,

> ```
> Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
>           (to execute a class)
>   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
>           (to execute a jar file)
> ...
>    -D<name>=<value>
>              set a system property
> ```

So, you want

```
java -DtestArg=Sample -cp MY_CLASSPATH mypackage.MyMain
```

Or, in eclipse -

Goto "Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs". There you can set-up JRE installation(s) and  update the JVM arguments.