# How can I pass in a variable with VSCode

Tags: maven, selenium, junit, visual-studio-code, selenide

I currently have Java code that I'm running in a terminal.

The run command is as follows.

```
mvn test -Dtest=Weather -Darea="東京"
```

The pseudocode is as follows:

1. Makes a request to Google.
2. Searches for "Weather".
3. Selects the Yahoo link and follows the redirect.
4. Enters the area and searches.

What I don't know how to do is pass in a variable with VSCode to execute the same code.

How can I pass in a variable with VSCode?

**Weather.java**

```
package com.example.app;

import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.*;
import com.codeborne.selenide.Configuration;
import com.codeborne.selenide.WebDriverRunner;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.CsvFileSource;



class Weather {
  @ParameterizedTest
  @CsvFileSource(resources = "Weather.csv", numLinesToSkip = 1)
  void openWeather(String ward) {
    String area = System.getProperty("area");

    Configuration.browser = WebDriverRunner.CHROME;
    // Configuration.headless = true;

    // Googleトップページ
    open("https://www.google.co.jp/");

    // "天気"を検索
    $("input[type=text]").val("天気").pressEnter();

    // Youtube検索ページへ飛ぶ
    $x("//a[@href='https://weather.yahoo.co.jp/weather/jp/13/4410/13120.html']").click();

    $("#searchText").setValue(area);
    $("#yjw_button_search").click();
    $x("//a[text()= '" + ward + "']").click();

  }
}
```

I used this as reference.

[How to run a command in VS Code with launch.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43836861/how-to-run-a-command-in-vs-code-with-launch-json)

And I tried the following.
But That didn't work.

**launch.json**

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "java",
      "name": "Debug (Launch) - Current File",
      "request": "launch",
      "mainClass": "${file}",
      "args": "-Darea=\"東京\""
    }
 ]
}
```

Current versions are as follows:

- selenide:5.5.2
- VSCode:1.41.0
- junit:5.3.2

I am sorry that my English is bad.
If you have any questions, please don't hesitate to contact me.

Comment: you can use input variables https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_input-variables

Comment: @rioV8 I'm sorry for late repley. I'll try to use it! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

There is a distinct difference between java arguments and vm arguments.  Your command line instructions are using vm arguments. See [What's the difference between program arguments and VM arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751851/whats-the-difference-between-program-arguments-and-vm-arguments).

Set vm arguments like this:

```
    {
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "java",
      "name": "Debug (Launch) - Current File",
      "request": "launch",
      "mainClass": "${file}",
      "vmArgs": "-Darea=\"東京\""
    }
 ]
}
```