# Java: clarification of "argument for a long option" scenario

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

In Java, I have a clear understanding about:

- [What's the difference between program arguments and VM arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751851/whats-the-difference-between-program-arguments-and-vm-arguments)

The *program arguments* works through either `main(String[] args)` or `main(String... args)` in peace.

If you open your terminal and write just the `java`  term for command execution then the following output appears:

```
Usage: java [options] <mainclass> [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [options] -jar <jarfile> [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
   or  java [options] -m <module>[/<mainclass>] [args...]
       java [options] --module <module>[/<mainclass>] [args...]
           (to execute the main class in a module)
   or  java [options] <sourcefile> [args]
           (to execute a single source-file program)

 Arguments following the main class, source file, -jar <jarfile>,
 -m or --module <module>/<mainclass> are passed as the arguments to
 main class.

 where options include:

 .... //omitted


To specify an argument for a long option, you can use --<name>=<value> or
--<name> <value>.
```

In the beginning appears that `Arguments following the ...` (it to have clear what *argument* means in this context) and the bottom appears:

```
To specify an argument for a long option, you can use --<name>=<value> or
--<name> <value>
```

So, when would be mandatory use an approach over the other? `--<name>=<value>` vs `--<name> <value>` - it for the *argument for a long option* scenario - both options exists for a solid reason, right?
Some examples would be valuable.

Comment: there's no difference between --<name>=<value> or
--<name> <value> you may pick which way you prefer

Comment: Both options exist because Unix practice, evolved over decades, varies a lot. Some programs use `--option=value` and some other programs use `--option value` and most GNU programs use a standard library that supports both. Since some users may be familiar with one, and some with the other, and some with both, Java supporting both reduces the number of failures caused by people following their existing habits and experience rather than spending 90% of their time rereading the documentation before every single command they run.